# Maintain a jar file launched in Debian system

Tags: ssh, jar, selenium-webdriver, debian

In order to launch the standalone selenium server jar file in a remote debian server, I used the SSH connection to execute the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar
```

However, once the SSH connection is lost, the selenium server is down.

Could someone tell me what to do to reach my goal?

Comment: `nohup java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar &`

Comment: Actually, I can't get the selenium web driver tests running from a remote machine. I get the following error: cannot open display: 11.0 :(